# pprof how to get profile.pb.gz without using pprof -http

Tags: profile, pprof

I ues pprof -http to generate profiling result all the time, but every time i need profile.pb.gz i need go to the http web to download it.
[what i did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATRnC.png)
Is that anyway to generate profile.pb.gz with local binary,but no need to using pprof -http.

Comment: I think you can just download the file directly from the pprof endpoint of your service? No need to invoke the `pprof` tool.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the following command to download a file directly

```
go tool pprof -proto source
```

You can also refer [this](https://github.com/google/pprof/blob/master/doc/README.md) documentation on how to use pprof tool differently according to your use case.